# Using Refit to add tokens in Blazor wasm

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly, refit

Unsure why this does not work:

```
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("myApi").AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddRefitClient<IWeatherApi>()
    .ConfigureHttpClient(c =>
    {
        c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7252");

    })
    .AddHttpMessageHandler(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<AuthorizationMessageHandler>()
            .ConfigureHandler(new[] { "https://localhost:7252" }));
```

Using the client, I get the error shown below. I also tried registering the a `HttpClient` separately and adding it using:

```
RestService.For<IWeatherApi>(HttpClientFactory.CreateClient("myApi"));
```

But I'm still getting this error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Specified cast is not valid.
> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
>
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.WebAssemblyAuthenticationServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__0`3[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteUserAccount, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.ApiAuthorizationProviderOptions, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].b__0_0(IServiceProvider sp)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: This error message is related to type conversion, so you need to enable logging to track errors.

Comment: Or you can provide sample source code that can reproduce the problem, and I will investigate it for you. Please be careful not to include any confidential information.